# oracle - sequences without a sequence

Tags: oracle, sequence

I want to populate a column with a sequential number but a single sequence is not sufficient. This column will behave somewhat like a 'sub id' if you will; an incrementing id for groups of records in the table.

The plan is to get the 'next number in the sequence' when inserting using a trigger, much like a normal `sequence` may be used. However, rather than just the 'next number', it needs to be the 'next number' in a given result set.

Consider the following example data where the `display_id` column is the sequence I need help managing and it is dependent on the record's value for `group_name`..

```
 id | group_name | display_id
------------------------------
  5 |   GroupA   |     3
  4 |   GroupA   |     2
  3 |   GroupA   |     1
  2 |   GroupB   |     2
  1 |   GroupB   |     1
```

I'm thinking of a query like this query to get the 'next number' for `GroupA`:

```
select max(record_id) + 1
from my_records
where group_name = 'GroupA'
```

For `GroupA` it returns 4, but for `GroupB` it returns 3.

We could, of course, use the above query but would lose the atomic benefits of a `sequence`. Is there any way to manage such a sequence confidently?

<s>We are not concerned about potentially skipping numbers (as sequences may).</s>

**Edit:**
We are comfortable with a number or two being missed due to rollbacks and the like (as with sequences). However, our requirement is still that the `display_id` column maintain multiple sequences.

Comment: You'd better explained the original task. Your current solution attempt doesn't look well. *Why* not use sequence?

Comment: If you don't care about skipping numbers, is there a reason that you don't use a single Oracle sequence and just use an analytic function at query time if you're trying to figure out which row is the Nth row with a `my_other_column` value of "some value"?

Comment: @zerkms ok, I'll beef it up in a second

Comment: @JustinCave I don't think I explained myself well, let me improve the question a bit. Regarding query time functions, it's not an option here because we want this value to be assigned to a record permanently. Regarding using a normal Oracle sequence, it would skip around too much heh, we don't mind skipping by one every so often.

Comment: @Sean Connolly: new question version still doesn't explain *why* not use sequences

Comment: Hey @zerkms, I can't think how better to explain it than with the example data. If I used a sequence I wouldn't get the behavior I show in the example data, right? I'd get a single increasing number. Unless I'm missing something?

Comment: @Sean Connolly: "If I used a sequence I wouldn't get the behavior I show in the example data, right?" -- right, if you used the solution from example you would get issues with concurrency. For now I cannot see how a solution affected by possible condition race issues is better than a thread-safe one. "I'd get a single increasing number." --- and you said - "We are not concerned about potentially skipping numbers"

Comment: @zerkms if I use the solution I propose, one could insert the 'correct next number', not commit, then another can insert the same 'correct next number' and when both commit, we have duplicates. Sequences avoid this by being atomic and increasing, even if changes aren't committed. I get the feeling I must be missing something glaring here?

Comment: @Sean Connolly: you're not missing anything. The thing is - your current solution doesn't fit your requirements. And you didn't explain what the "correct next number" is. What requirement doesn't the sequence fit to be a correct next number? "Sequences avoid this by being atomic and increasing, even if changes aren't committed." -- so what?

Comment: Hmmm, I'm confused. I've just created that example table and data and the solution works just fine. How does it not fit my requirements? I explained that the 'correct next number' is 4 for 'GroupA' and 3 for 'GroupB'. A real sequence would return 6 or something. "so what?".. so a sequence is atomic and guarantees numbers returned are unique.

Comment: @Sean Connolly: "and the solution works just fine" --- until you get 2 requests simultaneously. "A real sequence would return 6 or something." --- and **you said** you're fine with that "We are not concerned about potentially skipping numbers". "I explained that the 'correct next number' is 4 for 'GroupA' and 3 for 'GroupB'." and you said you're fine with skipping numbers. "so a sequence is atomic and guarantees numbers returned are unique." -- isn't that great?

Comment: Awh dude, I think you're messing with me now.. "until you get 2 requests simultaneously" sounds a lot like my question: "the above query but would lose the atomic benefits of a sequence. Is there any way to manage such a sequence confidently?"

Comment: @zerkms.. I don't understand why you're taking this stance with me? I have a question and I've come to the community looking for help is all.

Comment: @Sean Connolly: yes there is - use sequences. Now, according to your "We are not concerned about potentially skipping numbers" statement sequences **is** the valid solution.

Comment: @Sean Connolly: uhm, what "stance"? o_O You've asked the question - I've answered "use sequences". That simple.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24928/discussion-between-zerkms-and-sean-connolly)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although I would strongly recommend against it (preferring to use a single sequence and just accept that there will be larger than expected gaps), you can build your own pseudo-sequence table

```
CREATE TABLE my_sequences (
  sequence_name VARCHAR2(30) PRIMARY KEY,
  sequence_val  NUMBER
);
```

insert a couple of rows

```
INSERT INTO my_sequences( sequence_name, sequence_val )
  VALUES( 'GroupA', 1 );
INSERT INTO my_sequences( sequence_name, sequence_val )
  VALUES( 'GroupB', 1 );
```

and then write a function to get the next sequence value

```
CREATE FUNCTION get_nextval( p_sequence_name IN VARCHAR2 )
  RETURN NUMBER
IS
  l_val NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT sequence_val
    INTO l_val
    FROM my_sequences
   WHERE sequence_name = p_sequence_name
     FOR UPDATE;

  UPDATE my_sequences
     SET sequence_val = sequence_val + 1
   WHERE sequence_name = p_sequence_name;

  RETURN l_val;
END;
```

This will lock the row in the table for the particular sequence until the transaction that retrieved the next row either commits or rolls back.  This will radically decrease the scalability of your application compared to using Oracle sequences by ensuring that only one session can be inserting a row for a particular `group_name` at a time-- the others will block waiting for the sequence.  If you have a system with a relatively small number of concurrent users (or a relatively large number of `group_name` values), that may be acceptable to you.  But in general it is a poor practice.  Depending on the Oracle version, you may be able to use autonomous transactions to increase concurrency but that just adds one more bit of complexity to the solution.  At the point that you're really worried about scalability, you'd really want to push back on the whole design and just use an Oracle sequence.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer Justin. This solution seems like the simples and most straight forward given the requirements. I think, however, I'll follow your last point and push back on the requirements. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Create an unique composite index on `group_name + display_id` columns.

Then use your code and in case exception is thrown - re-run the next value generation.

PS: personally I don't like it, but it's likely in this case there is no good alternatives